# .htaccess per directory in nginx

Tags: nginx, .htaccess

I am new to nginx and I have been on apache before.

In apache, each directory can have a .htaccess to target the directory and and it's subdirectories.

Is this possible for nginx? If so, how do I do that?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nginx doesn't have .htaccess support nor even any kind of per-directory configuration files in which users can modify configuration.  Also no any kind of runtime configuration changes (kill -HUP needed to reload config). But anyway nginx mostly used for reverse proxying

Answer (score 2):

```
.htaccess
```

is a workaround (kind of a "duct tape") for shared hosting environments.
It has a performance (speed) penalty.

read prooflink from NGiИX developers:
https://nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/likeapache-htaccess/

http://www.nginxtips.com/why-doesnt-nginx-support-htaccess-files/

So
the main rule when you configuring (migrating from apache) is: NEVER USE CONVERTERS!!!

Look at `location` and `try_files` directives instead:

https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location

http://nginxtips.com/nginx-location-directive/

https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files

https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html

Answer (score 0):

nginx doesn't have .htaccess support, you should add all the configuration to nginx standard conf.